# sendmessage or Postmessage in vba

Tags: vba

I have to mimic key combinations of control and tab, but am unable to getit done. Can any one help me on API postmessage or sendmessage in vba to simulate combination of keys like control and tab

```
lOk = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0&, vbNullString, hwndtext) 
j = SendMessage(hwnd, TAB_KEYDOWN, 0&, 0&)
 j = PostMessage(hwnd, TAB_KEYDOWN, 0&, 0&)
'Cannot post entire code as this is restricted
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO Is not a "Code for Me", "Teach me to Code", or a "Show where to Start" site. It is a place for those with existing code with specific problems to get specific help on overcoming that problem. If you have code that you have tried that is not working please put it in your original post using edit and explain what the code is doing in error. As is, this is too broad for this forum and risks down votes and closure.

Comment: lOk = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0&, vbNullString, hwndtext)
        j = SendMessage(hwnd, TAB_KEYDOWN, 0&, 0&)
        j = PostMessage(hwnd, TAB_KEYDOWN, 0&, 0&)'Cannot post entire code as this is restricted

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. Just edit your question (above) and post the relevant parts there.